# Unable to include custom font in html (Helvetica LT 25 Ultra Light)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I have downloaded the entire Helvetica Neue. Almost all the fonts work when I try to import them, but "Helvetica LT 25 Ultra Light" does not.

Anyidea what the issue could be ?

code:

```
@font-face{
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
src: url('/fonts/Helvetica LT 25 Ultra Light.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

When using web fonts, you need to remember that different browsers require different file types. [This page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webfonts/quick/) includes a comprehensive tutorial spelling out how to use @font-face.
Basically, the only browsers that will display truetype fonts are Opera and Safari. Firefox, Chrome, and IE9 use 'woff' files. If you test your code in Opera or Safari, it should display correctly.

Update:

[Here's a site](http://webfonts.fonts.com/en-US) that makes it easier to include the font you're looking to use. They create a kit that you drop into your pages and you don't have to worry about creating/finding all the different formats yourself.

Answer (score 0):

add it in your html file :

```
<style type="css/text">
    @font-face{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
    src: url(' YOUR FOLDER /fonts/Helvetica LT 25 Ultra Light.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
</style>
```

relace **YOUR FOLDER**

Comment: still did not help. And I actually am using the complete path (from "http")
I can see that the browser is attempting to download it, but it falls back to another font in the end of it.